# AFNetworking Not Recognizing MAMP

Tags: ios, macos, mamp, afnetworking

I'm working on converting some NSURLConnection code over to AFNetworking and I'm seeing a strange issue where it won't recognize my local MAMP.

Here is the error message I get from NSURLConnection

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x160cb0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8888/webservices/poll.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8888/webservices/poll.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x15f910 "Could not connect to the server."}`

NSURLConnection was playing nicely with MAMP and I don't have any trouble connecting to remote servers with AFNetworking. Further, pasting the failed URL into my browser works just fine.

Here is the code I'm using

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/webservices/"]];
    [client getPath:@"poll.php"
         parameters:nil
            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);
            }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error");
                NSLog(@"%@", error);                                     
            }];
```

I can work from a remote server, but it would be nice to be able to make changes locally without having to upload files on every edit to test. I've seen several snippets of AFNetworking code that reference local servers. Any ideas what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using the ip address of your computer instead of localhost.

Comment: That did it. I just realized I've been testing on device (where localhost wouldn't have worked anyway). I suspect running from the simulator would have worked as well.

Comment: I recently experienced this same issue (MAMP, XCode 5, AFNetworking 2.0) and switching to the IP address fixed the issue. However, prior to *something* changing (I can't figure out what/where changed) I was able to use localhost to test on device.